# Java GUI - remove all components and redraw

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, grid-layout

I have a grid layout JPanel, with many icons drawn on it. I need the icons to change after the player moves because the map changes. Here's the method I came up with:

```
public void initGridIcons(JPanel pnl, String map) {
    pnl.removeAll();
    char[] tiles = map.toCharArray();
    for (char ch : tiles) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        String icon = "";
        switch (ch) { // lots of cases irrelevant to problem
        }
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ClientGUI.class
                .getResource("/resources/" + icon)));
        pnl.add(label);
    }
}
```

This works initially, in that it does draw the player and the map correctly. However it doesn't change after each turn.

I've tried using this method just with an iterator counter (change on even numbers) to make sure it wasn't any other code, and it doesn't work, so I'm sure it's this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may work initially before the applications's container `JFrame` is made visible, but calls to `revalidate` and `repaint` would be necessary on the `JPanel` to get it to work at runtime.

```
for (char ch : tiles) {
   ...
   pnl.add(label);
}

pnl.revalidate();
pnl.repaint();
```

If the number of `Icons` to be set is a fixed number, then `JLabel#setIcon` can simply be called to change the icons.